# Amount changes after using number_format php

Tags: php, decimal

I have a small problem. i have got an amount that has multiple numbers after the comma.

The amount is 89,3500205 and when i use the number_format or an other format function it changes the amount to 89,00 instead of 89,35.

I am doing

```
<?= echo number_format($var, 2); ?>
```

Does anyone has an suggestion for this problem?

Thx

Comment: Hi John,

<?= echo number_format($var, 2); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not getting a `A non well formed numeric value encountered` error?
Is your error_reporting on?

Try replacing `,` to `.`

```
echo number_format(str_replace(",",".",$var),2);
```